# Draw a circle with smoothline - Kivy, python

Tags: python, kivy

I noticed when you add graphics in kivy, it looks very rough. How can I draw an ellipse with smoothline?

```
canvas:

    Color: 
        rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1

    Ellipse:
        size: (372, 372)
        pos: (root.width / 2 - 186), (root.height / 2 - 186)
        segments: 1
```

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Ellipse drawing instruction has no SmoothLine equivalent, although it would be possible to create one (and such a contribution would probably be welcome).

Possible workarounds for your antialiasing issue might be:

- Make sure Kivy is using hardware antialiasing (see 'multisamples' at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html), although this may not help much.
- Draw an Ellipse as you already are, but also draw a SmoothLine in the shape of the ellipse boundary.